# To copy the data from all (many) the excel workbook inside many subfolders and copy it to another excel workbook

Tags: excel, vbscript

below is the code to loop through all the excel workbook in every subfolder(looping through subfolders) and copying data from each and every excel workbook and appending onto another excel workbook. Excecuting the below code I am getting an error as "Object doesn't support this property or method:'objsubfolder.files'" please help me with this.

```
'Sub RunCodeOnAllXLSFiles()

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

strPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\SupriyaS\Desktop\su"
pathName="xlsx"

if strPath = "" then Wscript.quit
if pathName = "" then Wscript.quit

'Creating an Excel Workbook in My Documents
Set objWorkbook2= objExcel.Workbooks.Add()

objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder (strPath)
Set objsubFolder = objfolder.subFolders
set objfile = objsubfolder.files

for each objsubfoleder in objfolder.subfolders

For Each objFile In objsubFolders.Files

If objFso.GetExtensionName (objFile.Path) = "xlsx" Then
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path)

Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.WorkSheets(1)
objworksheet.Activate

' Select the range on Sheet1 you want to copy 
objWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET1").usedrange.Copy

objworkbook.close

Set objRange = objExcel.Range("A1")
intNewRow = objExcel.ActiveCell.Row + 3
strNewCell = "A" &  intNewRow
objExcel.Range(strNewCell).Activate

' Paste it on sheet1 of workbook2, starting at A1
objWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strNewCell).PasteSpecial

Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook2.Worksheets(1)

End If
next
next
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying data from many excel workbook to another excel workbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784752/copying-data-from-many-excel-workbook-to-another-excel-workbook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted as answer just to be able to say:

***USE Option Explicit***

(and Dim and initialize all your variables (immediately) before first use)

to avoid to be bitten by typos like "objsubfoleder"

Comment: Thank you, but even after declaring all the variables, its not working ,its throwing an error "Object doesn't support this property or method:'files'"