# Copying data from many excel workbook to another excel workbook

Tags: excel, vbscript

i am new to vb script and dont know much so please help.

I have a folder, which consists of many sub-folders . Each sub-folder has 10+ excel sheets in it. My aim is to copy the data from each and every excel file from all the sub-folders to a single excel sheet. the problem is i have written a code, but it is overwriting so the data gets deleted. And we have same header in all the excel files, i want the header to appear only once in the main excel sheet .
please help and thnakyou in advance.

```
'Sub RunCodeOnAllXLSFiles()
On Error Resume Next


Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")


strPath = ":\Documents and Settings\faizat\Desktop\leeza"
pathName="xlsx"


If strPath = "" Then WScript.quit
If pathName = "" Then WScript.quit


'Creating an Excel Workbook in My Documents
Set objWorkbook2= objExcel.Workbooks.Add()


objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False


Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder (strPath)
Set objsubFolder = objfolder.subFolders
Set objfile = objsubfolder.files


For Each objsubfolder In objfolder.subfolders

    For Each objFile In objsubFolder.Files


        If objFso.GetExtensionName (objFile.Path) = "xlsx" Then
            Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path)


            Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.WorkSheets(1)
            objworksheet.Activate


            ' Select the range on Sheet1 you want to copy 
            objWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET1").usedrange.Copy


            objworkbook.close




            Set objRange = objExcel.Range("A2")
            intNewRow = objExcel.ActiveCell.Row + 10
            strNewCell = "A" & intNewRow
            objExcel.Range(strNewCell).Activate

            For i = 1 To usedrange
                objWorksheet.Cells(intNewRow, 1) = i * 1
                intNewRow = intNewRow + i
            Next

            ' Paste it on sheet1 of workbook2, starting at A1
            objWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strNewCell).PasteSpecial

            Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook2.Worksheets(1)

        End If
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For i = 1 To usedrange
    objWorksheet.Cells(intNewRow, 1) = i * 1
    intNewRow = intNewRow + i
Next
```

You never initialize the variable `usedrange`, so your loop never increments `intNewRow`. Initialize `intNewRow` with the value 1 at the beginning of your script, and use something like this in the inner loop:

```
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path)

If intNewRow = 1 Then
  startrow = 1
Else
  startrow = 2
End If
endrow = objWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

objWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET1").Range(startrow & ":" & endrow).Copy
objWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(intNewRow, 1).PasteSpecial

objWorkbook.close

intNewRow = intNewRow + (endrow - startrow - 1)
```